# Zooming in on a cluster eventually resolves to a single pin

Tags: azure-maps

I have a case with 3 pins at the same location. Zoomed out it renders as a cluster. But when I zoom in, generally somewhere between 16 & 18, it changes to a single pin.

What's going on here? Shouldn't it remain a cluster even at maximum zoom? Is there a way to keep it clustered? Because this way, the other 2 pins are gone - the user cannot access them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DataSource class has an option called `clusterMaxZoom` which specifies the maximum zoom level the map will cluster points to. This is set to 18 by default. If you have points that will be at the same location, it would best to set this to 24 (max possible zoom level of the map). You can either set this when creating the data source or update the options afterwards. It would be better to set this before adding your data so that it calculates the clusters once.

```js
var myDataSource = new atlas.source.DataSource(null, { 
    cluster: true, 
    clusterMaxZoom: 24 
});
```

or

```js
myDataSource.SetOptions({ clusterMaxZoom: 24 });
```

Comment: Thank you. And out of curiosity, why does it, by default, stop clustering? TIA

Comment: In most applications the cluster radius is a decent size (40+ pixels) and at zoom level 18, that equates to a distance of over 23 meters which is often far enough apart and at which point users are fine with nearby pins overlapping a bit. Ultimately the reason for this being the default is that this feature is exposed in Azure Maps as-is from the underlying library Azure Maps Web SDK wraps, MapLibre, and that's the default used there.  To be honest, this is one of the few times I've come across someone who needed it to be something else.

Comment: My use case is akin to an app that shows where concerts are happening. You'll have clusters at every concert venue and for all concerts at that venue, it's the exact same location. You're right it's likely rare.

Comment: Another idea, if there isn't a massive number of events at the same location is to show a pin for each one and use offsets to create a grid like pattern for the pins. I haven't done this before but swear I've seen it once. Would require a bit of extra work as you would need to analyze the data before displaying it, find all the locations that have multiple events, then calculate their offsets. Then add that as a property of the event point and use data driven styling for displaying. Then, limit clustering to zoom 18 or lower, and if the user goes closer, show individual pins that are offset.

Comment: That is a cool idea. But for now I'm going with cluster all the way down and waiting for user feedback. thanks